# JPA: Convert SQL query to JPA query

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

How do I convert the following query to JPA query:

```
  select * from (select * from t1 where id=14 order by timestamp desc) as h group by hnumber order by timestamp desc limit 0, 15
```

I have tried it doing it like below but failed with syntax error.

```
  select m from (select n from t1 n where n.id=:id order by timestamp desc) as m group by hnumber order by timestamp desc limit 0, 15
```

Please correct me, basically I need to fetch distinct records in descending order of timestamp. Any help is appreciated.

Updates:
the columns in the t1 table are:

```
  seq
  id
  message
  timestamp
  hnumber
```

Basically I need to get distinct rows for a id (id is like user) and hnumber (can be multiple) in the descending order of timestamp. Timestamp should be greater with in the id and hnumber.

Please note: the order of inserting to t1 table may not be in the order of timestamp. Each id can have different messages.

Update 2:

Here is an example:

```
    Seq     id  message timestamp       hnumber
    1001    14  xyz1    1394607463000   0429c3866c19981fc276855ff3cdaf100e0c9fdb
    1002    14  xyz2    1394608378000   0429c3866c19981fc276855ff3cdaf100e0c9fdb
    1003    14  xyz1    1394453678000   0429c3866c19981fc276855ff3cdaf100e0c9fdb
    1004    14  xyz2    1394608520000   0429c3866c19981fc276855ff3cdaf100e0c9fdb
    1005    14  xyz9    1394612791000   369d7cf7bd90fac78ef635b188e2a9952d77a8d1
    1006    14  xyz7    1394608513793   0429c3866c19981fc276855ff3cdaf100e0c9fdb
    1008    14  xyz6    1394608513793   0429c3866c19981fc276855ff3cdaf100e0c9fdb
    1009    14  xyz3    1394622221000   369d7cf7bd90fac78ef635b188e2a9952d77a8d1
    1010    14  xyz4    1394608513793   369d7cf7bd90fac78ef635b188e2a9952d77a8d1
```

Output I am expecting:

```
    Seq     id  message timestamp       hnumber
    1009    14  xyz3    1394622221000   369d7cf7bd90fac78ef635b188e2a9952d77a8d1
    1004    14  xyz2    1394608520000   0429c3866c19981fc276855ff3cdaf100e0c9fdb
```

Comment: Please can you show the columns in table t1 and examples of the data and what you are expecting to get back in your results? Are you sure you need the "order by" on the inner select? Surely it won't have an affect, as you aren't applying a limit on the inner select. Surely only the ordering and limit on your outer select will impact the results?

Comment: @Hedley I updated my post. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Please can you give a sample of (say) 10 rows of data, and then show what you would expect to get back as the results of the query, so that I can understand the ordering you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Hedley I updated my post. Please check. I included the example

Comment: How to write jpa method for this query?                                                                 
SELECT * FROM do_not_track WHERE (user_id=7 ) AND ('2022-06-25' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) OR ('2022-06-30' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date);

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong with this query, e.g. `LIMIT` is MySQL specific syntax. You could use `query.setFirstResult(0)` and `query.setMaxResults(15)` instead.

But the bigger problem is that subqueries are only supported in the SELECT and WHERE clause, not within FROM. See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries).

You might want to consider using your plain SQL version from above and pass it to `createSqlQuery(String)` (or `createNativeQuery(String)` if you're working with `EntityManager` API).

Note that those native SQL queries are not portable to a different RDBMS, though.

Comment: Yes, I use EntityManager. I understood about the LIMIT support in JPA. If I try to use native query in first post, a dead lock is happening. Not sure why. I just wanted to use createSqlQuery instead. I am trying to convert the above query to JPA query.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as an HQL correlated subquery, to avoid having a join in the from clause. e.g. the following query will return the most recent messages of each hnumber for a given id

```
select um.id,um.hnumber,um.message from UserMessage as um 
  where um.timestamp in (
    select max(timestamp) from UserMessage um1 
      where um1.id=:id and um1.hnumber=um.hnumber group by id,hnumber
    )
```

You didn't specify the name of the entity that you are using to map your table T1, so in the above, I have called it "UserMessage".

The general form, to get results for the entire table, is:

```
select um.id,um.hnumber,um.message from UserMessage as um 
  where um.timestamp in (
    select max(timestamp) from UserMessage um1 
      where um1.id=um.id and um1.hnumber=um.hnumber group by id,hnumber
    )
```

You can see that the inner subquery is a correlated subquery, because it refers to elements from the outer query - um.id and um.hnumber.

I've put a working example of this query on github here:

https://github.com/hedleyproctor/hibernate-mapping-and-query-examples

If you look in the Tests class you will see a test called "hqlWithCorrelatedSubquery". It uses the sample data from above, and gives output as:

```
Printing results for query against entire table:
14
0429c3866c19981fc276855ff3cdaf100e0c9fdb
1394608520000
xyz2
14
369d7cf7bd90fac78ef635b188e2a9952d77a8d1
1394622221000
xyz3
```

As a general rule, many simple SQL expressions that involve a join in the from clause can be rewritten as a correlated subquery, to permit them to be converted to HQL or a Hibernate Criteria query. In theory a correlated subquery could be slow if it is executed over a range, since unlike a join, the correlated subquery "should" be evaluated repeatedly for every row in the outer result set, but in practice many database query optimisers will process it in the same way as the equivalent join query, by creating the inner query results as a lookup table in a single operation, so the performance will be identical.

Comment: this query actually fetched all the records from t1.

Comment: I have added a worked example to github. Please can you run it and compare against what you are seeing. If you have a dataset that the query doesn't work with, please can you update your question with a larger set of sample data, or fork the github project and put the dataset in src/test/resources and I will have a look. Thanks.